# Dynamic sql with pivot/unpivot

Tags: oracle11g

I want to flip all rows to columns. So if have following 5 columns
with 3 data rows

```
ACCT_ID       NAME           PHONE              MOBILE      ALTERNATIVE_NAME
01          JOE BROWN        0456-9992-6666    07767828432       ZOE BROWN
02          GILL SHARP       0456-9992-6666    07763928432       BILL SHARP
03          ZAC LOWE         0236-9992-5644    07663925672       LUKE LOWE
```

I want the result set to look as follows. So have 3 columns and 5 rows.

COL headings (COL1 - COL3) are only added to make clearer, i don't need
columns headings

```
COL1                        COL2                             COL3

01                           02                               03    
JOE BROWN                    GILL SHARP                      ZAC LOWE  
0456-9992-6666               0456-9992-6666                  0236-9992-5644
07767828432                  07763928432                     07663925672
ZOE BROWN                    BILL SHARP                      LUKE LOWE
```

The following SQL will work if know the acct_id's. But i wont know the acct_id, so need to write some dynamic sql to select the acct_id from table REPORTER.TEMP_PSR_REGION and then do the pivot/unpivot.

```
CREATE TABLE REPORTER.TEMP_PSR_REGION
  (
     ACCT_ID             VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     NAME                VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     PHONE               VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     MOBILE              VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     ALTERNATIVE_CONTACT VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  )

INSERT INTO TEMP_PSR_REGION
            (ACCT_ID,
             NAME,
             PHONE,
             MOBILE,
             ALTERNATIVE_CONTACT)
VALUES     ('01',
            'JOE BROWN',
            '0456-9992-6666',
            '07767828432',
            'ZOE BROWN')
INSERT INTO TEMP_PSR_REGION
            (ACCT_ID,
             NAME,
             PHONE,
             MOBILE,
             ALTERNATIVE_CONTACT)
VALUES     ('02',
            'GILL SHARP',
            '0456-9992-6666',
            '07763928432',
            'BILL SHARP')
INSERT INTO TEMP_PSR_REGION
            (ACCT_ID,
             NAME,
             PHONE,
             MOBILE,
             ALTERNATIVE_CONTACT)
 VALUES     ('03',
            'ZAC LOWE',
            '0236-9992-5644',
            '07663925672',
            'LUKE LOWE')

--- PIVOT/UNPIVOT Example  
select col1, col2, col3
from (
  select t.*, t.acct_id as col_id
  from TEMP_PSR_REGION t
)
unpivot
(
  value FOR heading in (acct_id, name, phone, mobile, ALTERNATIVE_CONTACT)
)
pivot
(
  max(value) for col_id in ('01' as col1, '02' as col2, '03' as col3)                     
)
order by case heading 
 when 'ACCT_ID'             then 1 
 when 'NAME'                then 2 
 when 'PHONE'               then 3
 when 'MOBILE'              then 4 
 when 'ALTERNATIVE_CONTACT' then 5 
 end
```

What would the dynamic sql look like to do this. I have not written dynamic sql before?

Comment: Can anyone help with the dynamic sql for Oracle to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pivot's `IN` clause with a query:

```
select listagg('''' || acct_id || ''' as col' || rownum, ', ') within group (order by acct_id)
from TEMP_PSR_REGION;

LISTAGG(''''||ACCT_ID||'''ASCOL'||ROWNUM,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYACCT_ID)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
'01' as col1, '02' as col2, '03' as col3
```

You can then use that as part of a query to generate the dynamic SQL statement, and then open that statement as a ref cursor. In this example I'm using a SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer or SQLcl) client `refcursor` variable to simplify how to declare and sisplay it:

```
var rc refcursor

declare
  l_sql varchar2(32767);
begin
  select 
   q'[
select *
from (
  select t.*, t.acct_id as col_id
  from TEMP_PSR_REGION t
)
unpivot
(
  value FOR heading in (acct_id, name, phone, mobile, ALTERNATIVE_CONTACT)
)
pivot
(
  max(value) for col_id in (]'
|| listagg('''' || acct_id || ''' as col' || rownum, ', ') within group (order by acct_id)
|| q'[)                     
)
order by case heading 
 when 'ACCT_ID'             then 1 
 when 'NAME'                then 2 
 when 'PHONE'               then 3
 when 'MOBILE'              then 4 
 when 'ALTERNATIVE_CONTACT' then 5 
 end]'
into l_sql
from TEMP_PSR_REGION;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_sql); -- for debugging only
  open :rc for l_sql;
end;
/
```

Most of that is your original query. Essentially it puts your query into a string variable, but changes

```
select col1, col2, col3
from (
...
```

to

```
q'[
select *
from (
...]'
```

though you could generate that select-list with another `listagg()` if you prefer; and more importantly:

```
...
pivot
(
  max(value) for col_id in ('01' as col1, '02' as col2, '03' as col3)                     
)
...
```

to:

```
q'[...
pivot
(
  max(value) for col_id in (]'
|| listagg('''' || acct_id || ''' as col' || rownum, ', ') within group (order by acct_id)
|| q'[)                     
)
...]'
```

When that block is executed the `dbms_output` debug shows the generated statement, which is the same as your original once `listagg()` has been evaluated:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*, t.acct_id as col_id
  from TEMP_PSR_REGION t
)
unpivot
(
  value FOR heading in (acct_id, name, phone, mobile, ALTERNATIVE_CONTACT)
)
pivot
(
  max(value) for col_id in ('01' as col1, '02' as col2, '03' as col3)                     
)
order by case heading 
 when 'ACCT_ID'             then 1 
 when 'NAME'                then 2 
 when 'PHONE'               then 3
 when 'MOBILE'              then 4 
 when 'ALTERNATIVE_CONTACT' then 5 
 end

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

And you can display the opened ref cursor:

```
print rc

COL1                                               COL2                                               COL3                                              
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
01                                                 02                                                 03                                                
JOE BROWN                                          GILL SHARP                                         ZAC LOWE                                          
0456-9992-6666                                     0456-9992-6666                                     0236-9992-5644                                    
07767828432                                        07763928432                                        07663925672                                       
ZOE BROWN                                          BILL SHARP                                         LUKE LOWE
```

Using `rownum` is slightly dodgy as the headings might be out of order (as there is no ordering), but it seems you don't care about those anyway. If it does turn out to matter you can use a subquery to assign a numeric index to each row in the base table and then use that value instead of `rownum`.

You could potentially put this in a function that returns a ref cursor, but it depends how you're going to call it and use the results. The `var` and `print` are just a demonstration and probably not what you would really use.

You might also want to consider letting a reporting layer, if you have one, deal with the pivoting.